# Unable to run a cryptonote forked coin, what are node seeds

Tags: cryptonote

I have compiled cryptonote fork on two different Azure Ubuntu 14.0.4 machines.
When I try and run the daemon o get this:
MYIP:MYPORT failed: TcpConnector::connect, connection failed

I think It has to do with the seed nodes configuration, what should I have there? The addresses and ports of one of them? local host?

Currently, I have the two instances running the same daemon with the IP and PORT of one of them.

P.s 
All ports are allowed in the FireWall both in and out

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for exact details but:

- try set seed=localhost on the first, and seed=node1 on the other
- be sure to change all the ports not to clash with existing CN cryptocurrencies
- be sure to change address prefix not to clash with existing CN cryptocurrencies
- if there are some check-points like embedded hashes in the source, you'd need to tweak those as well

Comment: Your node needs to get some initial list of nodes to connect to. Any node can be a seed node. It's the one you fetch the list of other nodes from and try to connect to them